# How do I translate the below javascript to C#?

Tags: c#, javascript

I don't understand how 's' is being used in '(+s[i])'.  What is the '+' for?  Also I do not understand the use of the || symbol in this way, what is it doing?

```
var draw = function(s){
...
if (+s[i]) a = (a+90)%360||360; // Right
else a = (a-90||360); // Left
```

In the code below I do not understand what 'while (n--)' does?

```
var getS = function(n){
    var s = '';
    while (n--) s += getNext(0);
    return s;
};
```

If you want to look at this code in context go to http://fractal.qfox.nl/ and press F12 to get the developer tools up and look for dragon.js in the scripts.  Please feel entirely free to post a complete translation to C# as well if you fancy the challenge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting + in front of an expression coerces it into a number, e.g. from a string.

The || operator has the value of its left side if that can convert to true, otherwise the value of its right side. And so a||b would mean "use a if it's not null, false, zero or an empty string, otherwise use b".

And `n--` will have boolean value false when n reaches zero.

Answer (score 2):

`if (+s[i])` is checking if s[i] exists and is a number != 0. In C# it would be the same as

```
int n;
if (int.TryParse(s[i], out n) && n != 0) { }
```

---

`a = (a-90||360);` is basically saying if leftside of || is null, undefined, false or zero, then take rightside. In C# it would look something like

```
a = (a-90 > 0)? a-90 : 360;
```

but `a` would have to be declared prior to that line.

---

`while (n--){ }` keeps repeating itself until n is 0. n must be declared prior to running that code though such as `var n = 10;`.  In C# it would be

```
int n = 10;
while (n >= 0)
{
    n--;
}
```

Comment: "if (+s[i]) is checking if s[i] exists and is a number". Not so. If `s[i]` is zero, it is a number, but it will fail that test because zero converts to false. Your C# version will correctly treat zero as a number also.